# Print this maximally long URL

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

### Task

This one is simple.  We want to compress a URL, but don't trust URL shorteners.

Write a program that prints to stdout (or a 0-argument function that returns) the following, working URL:

http://a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n.oo.pp.qqq.rrrr.ssssss.tttttttt.uuuuuuuuuuu.vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv.wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.me

Code golf, standard rules.

You may output uppercase or lowercase.

Leading or trailing whitespace is ok.

### Context

Explanation taken from the website:

> The domain is created to reach the maximum number of allowed characters (255 (really 253)) with an exponential curve in the length of the letters as you proceed through the alphabet. The formula used is "1 + 62 * (10/7)^(x-26)". To help illustrate this curve, reference the distribution on this spreadsheet. It's colorful because I like colors and wanted to do a progressive "rainbow" animation in CSS3.

Comment: Jesus, that sh*t crashed my browser...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>25</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žXAS.7Ƶ-t∞-m>×….me¬ýJ
```

-1 byte thanks to [*@Neil*'s analysis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199002/print-this-maximally-long-url#comment472958_199005) that `*(10/7)**` is the same as `/.7**`.
-3 bytes thanks to *@Grimmy* using a different formula and ingenious use of `ý`!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//8W@WEFTLjfGtS104oieLW0@w5figKYubWXCrMO9Sv//)

**Explanation:**

The formula used to get the correct amount of characters of the alphabet, where \$n\$ is the 1-based index of the alphabetic letter:
\$a(n) = \left\lfloor0.7^{(\sqrt{208}-n)}+1\right\rfloor\$

```python
žX                     # Push builtin "http://"
      Ƶ-               # Push compressed 208
        t              # Take the square-root of that: 14.422...
         ∞             # Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
          -            # Subtract each from the 14.422...: [13.442...,12.442...,...]
    .7     m           # Take 0.7 to the power of each of these: [0.008...,0.011...,...]
            >          # Increase each by 1: [1.008...,1.011...,...]
  AS                   # Push the lowercase alphabet as list of characters,
             ×         # and repeat each the calculated values amount of times as string
                       # (which implicitly truncates the floats to integers, and ignores
                       #  the floats beyond the length of the alphabet)
              ….me     # Push ".me"
                  ¬    # Push its head (the "."), without popping the ".me" itself
                   ý   # Join with delimiter. Normally it will use the top value as
                       # delimiter and joins the top-1'th list. In this case however, the
                       # top-1'th item is a string, so instead it will join the entire stack
                       # together. BUT, because the stack contains a list, it will instead
                       # only join all lists on the stacks by the "." delimiter
                    J  # And finally join the three strings on the stack together
                       # (after which this result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ƶ-` is `208`.

Comment: 05AB1E even has a builtin for "http://". I'm impressed

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Yep. `žX` is `"http://"`; `žY` is `"https://"` and `žZ` is `"http://www."` :)

Comment: [22](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9vc2FiaWX//0FTLjfGtS104oieLW0@w5figJ5tZcKqJy7DvcW@WMOs//8)

Comment: [21](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//8W@WEFTLjfGtS104oieLW0@w5figKYubWXCrMO9Sv//) (: Also, here's a [20 that almost works](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9vc2FiaWX//8W@WEFT4oiexrUkdC1vdD7Dl@KApi5tZcKsw71K//8) (1 extra `v`, 1 missing `z`).

Comment: @Grimmy Very nice! Both the new formula with `sqrt(208)` and how you've used the `ý` to join the list somewhere on the stack is ingenious! :D

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>86</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>81</s></sup> 77 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [mypetlion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65255/mypetlion)!!!
Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Shieru Asakoto](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71546/shieru-asakoto)!!!

```python
print(f"http://{'.'.join(chr(i+97)*int(1+.7**-i/120)for i in range(26))}.me")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEADAr4gXXSVNg6J@E5G5QauIl4jebjTnyXeNiYbWckGqMvBYa16sfYQR5kxIcotFop4nUH9w2kxKdWid7yGkwpAhsbLSsUs/Arzm2jm09gE)

Uses [Shieru Asakoto](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71546/shieru-asakoto)'s 0-based formula.

Comment: 81 bytes: `print(f"http://{'.'.join(chr(i+122)*int(1+62*1.43**i)for i in range(-25,1))}.me")`

Comment: @mypetlion Clever reshuffle of braced expressions - thanks! :-)

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEADAr4gXXSVNg6J@E5G5QauIl4jebjTnyXeNiYbWckGqMvBYa16sfYQR5kxIcotFop4nUH9w2kxKdWid7yGkwpAhsbLSsUs/Arzm2jm09gE "Python 3 – Try It Online") when using an alternative formula.

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto Was just adding that - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>41</s> 38 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Bubbler*

```apl
2⌽'mehttp://',∊'.',¨⍨⎕A⍴¨⍨⌊1+62×.7*⍒⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qn/6O2CQYgFpA2etSzVz03NaOkpMBKX19d51FHl7qeus6hFY96VwBVOD7q3QJh93QZapsZHZ6uZ671qHcSSOr/fwA)

Outputs the URL with the letters capitalised. Uses the 0 indexed formula \$ \lfloor 1 + 62 \times 0.7^{25-x} \rfloor \$, since \$ (\frac{10}{7})^{x-25} = ((\frac{7}{10})^{-1})^{x-25} = (\frac{7}{10})^{25-x}\$

#### Explanation:

```apl
2⌽                         ⍝ Rotate by two places (moving the 'me' to the end)
  'mehttp://'              ⍝ The start string
             ,             ⍝ Followed by
              ∊               ⍝ The flattened string of
               '.'            ⍝ A period
                  ,⍨¨         ⍝ Appended to the end of each of
                     ⎕A            ⍝ The uppercase alphabet
                       ⍴¨⍨         ⍝ Where each letter is repeated by
                          ⌊               ⍝ The floor of
                           1+             ⍝ 1 plus
                             62×          ⍝ 62 times
                                .7*       ⍝ 0.7 to the power of
                                   ⍒⎕A  ⍝ The range 26 to 1
```

Comment: are the final two dots in `,⍨¨` the equivalent of J's rank 0 adverb `"0`?  Does APL have the ability to specify other specific ranks?

Comment: @Jonah Yes, ¨ is the each function, which applies an operator to each element of the vector. I don't think you can specify rank with that specific function, though I'm not an expert with APL. Try asking Adam in chat

Comment: @Jonah `f¨` is like J's stdlib's `each`, or `f&.:>"0`. The `"0` part is `⍤0` in APL. Unfortunately, we don't have J's (new) `L:` (though I'm arguing for adding it as `⍥`).

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>61</s> <s>57</s> 55 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to @Neil*

```perl
say"http://",(map{$_ x(1+62/.7**(++$p-26))."."}a..z),me
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIpo6SkwEpfX0lHIzexoFolXqFCw1DbzEhfz1xLS0NbW6VA18hMU1NPSU@pNlFPr0pTJzf1//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Comment: I think `*(10/7)**` is the same as `/(7/10)**` or `/.7**`.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 77 bytes

Based on [@ShieruAsakoto's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199008/58563). Builds the URL recursively.

```javascript
f=n=>n>25?".me":(n?".".padEnd(2+.7**-n/120,Buffer([97+n])):"http://a")+f(-~n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCsIwEADQu8xqpjGJBqQYaAXBU4iL0GT8UCehjS69evSt3jN8wjotj1K15Jha40GGUUa3P4J5JfAo/4ApIZ4lolOm7zotdue2m9ObOS14OfRKrkQe7rUWb20AUoz6K9SmLGuek5nzDRmJ2g8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 108 bytes

```java
v->{var s="HTTP://";for(char c=64,t;++c<91;s+=(""+c).repeat(t/=Math.pow(.7,c-90))+c+".")t=62;return s+"ME";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pdBBS8MwGAbg@35FyKm12zsVmcyuuyleBsLEi3jIsnZN16ZZ8rVzjv32GepABBXE5xLy5SW8fIVoxaBYro@qMrUlVvg7GlIlskZLUrXGWdwzzaJUkslSOMdmQmm27zF2mjoS5I@2VktW@bdgTlbp1fMLE3blwi7K2N3pu8mTz/U/IlOWJcd2MN23wjKX8PvHx4eb4ZDHWW0DmfuhTEZXfYqjSE7GF7GLkoDzSIawqUkFBTRMZoJymHob4LovB@PzMIxkxMFDSkaXsU2psZq5iM9ueXw4xl2X@c5RWqFuCMb3oFIHGYQx5S7QTVmG4Y8xnhMZX1FgAYklUmRYIYdCgTVKVNCoaxiDzWYD68F1QCdoPqH9Cttv4fV32P0B3v4HVcq7/Rx6h@M7)

### Credits

- -4 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: Very likely golfable using math.

Comment: -3 byte using `62/Math.pow(.7,c-122)` (credit goes to [_@Neil_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199002/print-this-maximally-long-url#comment472958_199005)).

Comment: And an additional -1 with `for(char c=96,t;++c<123;s+=(""+c).repeat(t/=Math.pow(.7,c-122))+c+".")t=62;`

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
http://⭆β⁺×ι⊕×⁶²Ｘ·⁷⁻²⁵κ.¦me
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREMpo6SkwEpfX0nTmgsiElwCpNJ9Ews0knQUAnJKizVCMnNTizUydRQ885KLUnNT80pSU6CCZkZANfnlqUUaeuY6Cr6ZeUDlRqY6CtmaIKCjoKSnBKRhRivlpgLt@f//v25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
http://                     Implicitly print literal string `http://`
        β                   Lowercase alphabet
       ⭆                    Map over letters and join
                      κ     Current index
                   ⁻²⁵      Subtract from 25
                Ｘ·⁷         Raise 0.7 to that power
             ×⁶²            Multiply by 62
            ⊕               Increment
          ×ι                Repeat letter that many times
         ⁺             .    Concatenate literal string `.`
                        ¦   Implicitly print
                         me Implicitly print literal string `me`
```

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, <s>[49](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/b0uzh7h6ueCMzFUM9E2Otw9PNjB41zHi4Y97h6YfbuYzMgg63Zz1qmKP3qGEuF5DOKCkpKLbS1wdyrQ8tsgbJ5KYCOf//AwA)</s> <s>[48](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/b0uzh7h6ueCMzFUM9E2Otw9PNjB41zHi4Y97h6YfbuYzMgg63Zz1qmKvH9ahhTkZJSUGxlb4@kG99aJE1UEQvNxXI@f8fAA)</s> <s>[46](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/b0uzh7h6ueCMzFUM9E2Otw9PNjB41zHi4Y97h6YfbuYzMgg63Zz1qmKvH9ahhTkZJSYGVvj6Qa31okTVQQC839f9/AA)</s> 31 bytes (send help)

A niladic link printing the URL

```
26RU.7*×89ĊØa×⁾meṭj”.“http://”;
```

-2 bytes thanks to Kevin

-15 bytes thanks to Nick!

I never wrote anything this complex in Jelly and the [*tacicity*](https://youtu.be/iywaBOMvYLI) isn't obvious to me yet... So this is very golfable (see 49 byte link). I would appreciate feedback and golfing tips in small chunks so that I can digest it!

You can [try this online](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/ILChUz1zr8HQLyyNdh2ckHp7@qHFfburDnWuzHjXM1XvUMCejpKTASl8fyLP@/x8A).

Comment: Your `https://` can be `http://` ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen gosh, I missed this entirely :D ty

Comment: Np. Unfortunately I can't really help you with the rest, since I don't know a lot about Jelly. Only thing that comes to mind is removing the trailing `”`, since it's closed implicitly to save a byte. But since my 05AB1E answer is 23 bytes, I'm sure <30 should be easily possible for Jelly as well. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I don't doubt that. It's just that Jelly is still so weird for me :p thanks for your input

Comment: Here’s [a 31 byte answer](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/ILChUz1zr8HQLyyNdh2ckHp7@qHFfburDnWuzHjXM1XvUMCejpKTASl8fyLP@/x8A) for comparison. In general, it’s helpful to try to have a single link that proceeds from left to right whenever possible. Other useful hints include use of `j` (join) for your last line (though I’ve changed it to add the `me` earlier), use of the `Ø` nilads, reversing the order of the list rather than subtracting from 26. Happy for you to use my answer (and improve it if possible). Note it was derived from @KevinCruijsen’s answer. It’s longer because of the `“http://”`

Comment: @NickKennedy this was an unbelievable byte discount. I'll have to digest your submission calmly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 71 bytes

```
"http://"<>Array[Table[Alphabet[][[#]],1+1.43^(#-26)62]<>"."&,26]<>"me"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/V8po6SkwEpfX8nGzrGoKLEyOiQxKSc12jGnICMxKbUkOjY6Wjk2VsdQ21DPxDhOQ1nXyEzTzCjWxk5JT0lNx8gMxMpNVfof@x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 99 bytes

```c
n;f(i){for(i=printf("http://");i<33;)for(n=62/pow(.7,i++-32)+2;n--;)putchar(n?89+i:46);puts("me");}
```

*-3 or so bytes thanks to [Noodle9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9481/noodle9)!*

*-8 bytes thanks to [gastropner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75886/gastropner)!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBDoIwEEX3nIKwmkmtJK1BZSSehVQLk9DSQNUF4erW@pb//TwjB2NS8mSBcbPzAtyFhX20UI0xhrauKyS@aU34t75rVB3mDxzPBxZCaoVCkZeSMLyiGft8uV@ugttTg5SnFSr3zIk95WjpevbwnvmBxVaUGQtIxZ6@xk79sCY5uR8)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 93 bytes

```javascript
_=>`http://${[...Array(26)].map((x,i)=>Buffer(Array(1+.7**-i/120|0).fill(97+i))).join`.`}.me`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBDoIwEADAz3jYBdkCB4kmJdFvGGMbbHVJaZuCRqO@vR6c64z6oechcVwqHy4mW5nPsle3ZYk7IVbvIxHtU9IvaDd4oklHgOeaUfaHu7UmwT@bkrqiqFg0bf2pkSw7B9uuZESkMbBXpL40GZWH4OfgDLlwBQuI@Qc)

When turning the formula into 0-indexed, the formula becomes \$1+62\times(\frac{10}{7})^{x-25}=1+0.0083146\times0.7^{-x}\$, and then 0.0083146 is approximated by 1/120.

Comment: Same length variant: ``_=>`http://${"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxuz".replace(/./g,(x,i)=>x.repeat(1+.7**-i/120)+`.`)}me` ``

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcZLCsIwEADQu8xqpjGJBqQYaAXBU4iL0GT8UCehjS69evSt3jN8wjotj1K15Jha40GGUUa3P4J5JfAo/4ApIZ4lolOm7zotdue2m9ObOS14OfRKrkQe7rUWb20AUoz6K9SmLGuek5nzDRmJ2g8)

Comment: @Arnauld I suggest you post it as a separate answer because the approach is quite different on this. I've rolled back your golf to let you post it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 29 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;`http://{C®p.7**T´/#xÄ +'.}´
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O2BodHRwOi8ve0OucC43KipUtC8jeMQgKycufbQ&footer=YHg)

Comment: [29 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O2BodHRwOi8ve0OucC43KipUtC8jeMQgKycufbQ&footer=YHg)?

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks, I forgot that `**` exists

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>124</s> <s>115</s> 63 bytes

This is way better than my original approach. Thanks to @Giuseppe and @Grimmy

```r
cat("http://");cat(strrep(letters,1+62*.7^(25:0)),"me",sep=".")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREMpo6SkwEpfX0nTGsQtLikqSi3QyEktKUktKtYx1DYz0tIzj9MwMrUy0NTUUcpNVdIpTi2wVdJT0vz/HwA)

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcTBCoAwCADQf/HkSrY1qGDQrwQjhA4Fov6/9Q5PI67hCLe79FKAZJhzRXNVFnzYndVombc25f3EtvaaEkGGv5eBjOUASBEf); feel free to come to the [R golfing chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81960/golfr) if you wanna discuss ideas there :-)

Comment: @Giuseppe [65 based on your 69](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREMpo6SkwEpfX0nTGsQtLikqSi3QyEktKUktKtYx1DYz0tIzj9MwMrUy0NTUUcpNVdIpTi2wVdJT0vz/HwA).

Comment: @Giuseppe and Grimmy, thanks! Very impressive trimming.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 86 bytes

```hs
g(c,x)=replicate(floor$1+62*1.43**x)c++"."
f="http://"++(zip['a'..][-25..0]>>=g)++"me"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pdC9bsIwAATgPU9hWUgkcXv89GeoZJ6gGyNicIOduDi245gSePk0KhWoUoWE@LaT7parRLuVxvR9mRYPXcaD9EYXIspUGefCaMZe5/kMz0953mUFYxQ0UZxWMfq3yYQylh61X43FGFivHucvwHS9WPAyG6q1pL2w7V6G80DgAwU2kFAoUUHjE1sY1LBwDt6jaRqEAdofiL@wu8DXX9j/C911ONwAx/tgeCNJaqEt4WTjEjLwu7iM4d0SdYpB20hGRBHOyem4/hs)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>126</s> 123 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [S.S. Anne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89298/s-s-anne)

Some acrobatics needed to avoid having to include `cmath`.

```cpp
#import<map>
using s=std::string;s f(){s r="http://";for(float i=26,p=7456;i--;p*=.7)r+=s(1+62/p,122-i)+'.';return r+"me";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1LDoMgFADX5RTELpTiJyWtJiLeheCnJPIJPFbGs1vb5UwmGeV9tSp13rVVW5pmPGgXIczSjJcz3gUYjPQjSlHbFUcRYer7q7iIR7wUZI84iOwD4PumyfjiQrFsTgLWgrWlF93r3XJdVdw/RN2RQEUsnrRljS@fjFWa0LzOeZghBYsDzcyc8ePUFrCR2hYE7ej2nyqXAA/D78nRcX4B)

Comment: You could use `bits/stdc++.h` and use `cmath`'s functions.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I might misunderstand you, but that would take even more bytes to include than cmath.

Comment: But not `string` and `cmath` combined. Instead of `#import<string> #import<cmath>` (in this hypothetical solution) you could do `#import<bits/stdc++.h>`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Oh, I see what you mean! Had no idea about that one. Sadly it came out longer, doing that.

Comment: Well, then `string` can be replaced with `map` for -3 bytes.

Comment: *ahem* [123 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY1LDoMgFADX5RTELpTiJyWtJiLeheCnJPIJPFbGs1vb5UwmGeV9tSp13rVVW5pmPGgXIczSjJcz3gUYjPQjSlHbFUcRYer7q7iIR7wUZI84iOwD4PumyfjiQrFsTgLWgrWlF93r3XJdVdw/RN2RQEUsnrRljS@fjFWa0LzOeZghBYsDzcyc8ePUFrCR2hYE7ej2nyqXAA/D78nRcX4B)

Comment: @S.S.Anne Ah, nice one! Thought you were talking about the data type so had no idea where it was going :-P

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>46</s> 40 bytes

```
`3);://`0&(‡26   |⑻a+ⁿ⅍7
/⑻±Ëx/ℤ1+⑹*\.)`me
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wVjT2kpfP8FATeNRw0IjM86aRxN3J2o/atz/qLXXnEsfyDu08XB3hf6jliWG2o8m7tSK0dNMyE39/x8A)

A port of the Python 3 answer by Noodle9.

*-6 bytes due to using string compression and some other things*

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 94 bytes

```php
for($c='a',$s='http://',$i=-26;$i++;$c++,$s.='.')for($l=62/.7**$i;$l-->=0;$s.=$c);echo$s.'me';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtRCoAgEEQvs7ClqeFHQdvWWUIMBSOp7m/WzzCPeZNDLvOaa@7n1YBj3LCDmzE8T56MqRBZ2YEgSkngpKyrZtTY/ofEgzV6FAIiQVJq4Z4@AVxL3oWzdjw8Uikv)

Probably still golfable, uses the formula from the question and PHP's char incrementing

EDIT: saved 3 bytes with code reorganization

EDIT2: another byte less starting from `-26` and removing `($i-26)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

Conveniently, when multiplying a string with a non-whole positive number, Ruby truncates the number to determine how many times to repeat the string.

```ruby
puts"http://#{(?a..?z).map{|c|c*(1+62/0.7**(c.ord-122))}*?.}.me"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFgpo6SkwEpfX7lawz5RT8@@SlMvN7Gguia5JllLw1DbzEjfQM9cS0sjWS@/KEXX0MhIU7NWy16vVi83Ven/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) 92 bytes

```
b="";for i=1:26;b=b+repelem(char(96+i),floor(1+62*(10/7).^(i-26)))+".";end;"http://"+b+"me"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 809 bytes

```
{i}cc{{i}d}iiiic{i}iiccddddc{{d}iiiii}ddddc{d}dcc{{i}ddddd}c{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddc{{i}ddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiii}ddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddd}dddc{{d}iiii}iiic{{i}dddd}ddc{{d}iiii}iic{{i}dddd}dc{{d}iiii}ic{{i}dddd}c{{d}iiii}c{{i}dddd}ic{{d}iiii}dc{{i}dddd}iic{{d}iiii}ddc{{i}dddd}iiic{{d}iiii}dddc{{i}dddd}iiiic{{d}iiii}ddddc{{i}dddd}iiiiicc{{d}iiii}dddddc{{i}dddd}iiiiiicc{{d}iiii}ddddddc{{i}ddd}dddccc{{d}iii}iiic{{i}ddd}ddcccc{{d}iii}iic{{i}ddd}dcccccc{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}cccccccc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}i{c}c{{d}iii}dc{{i}ddd}ii{c}ccccc{{d}iii}ddc{{i}ddd}iii{c}{c}cc{{d}iii}dddc{{i}ddd}iiii{c}{c}{c}c{{d}iii}ddddc{{i}ddd}iiiii{c}{c}{c}{c}cccc{{d}iii}dddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiii{c}{c}{c}{c}{c}{c}ccc{{d}iii}ddddddc{{i}dddd}iiic{d}iic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFBDkMhCERP1EM10KasuzSc3aI1MIMszHfeIN9RX0992/fzmHOYi4xY1S1K4itW0aiQ/2LAvVXX413lyEFeh0AjEUaN2TWQaMcXvwzlcLzO@Y8kCEAHudQSS6u5kAPGgClQCJQBR8AJnACYdnzxNOw5SfH@vgGQAiJEEogwSWBDMp9KInZLxw5FuOg2FCV8OJ3dLeU5o9DZrOTNDmror7Ufc84f)

E.